# Mapping records to specific path in EMT when node names are duplicated

Tags: endeca

We have an Externally Managed Taxonomy (EMT) and have been using a node's name to map records to the hierarchy. We are now hitting a problem because some of the node names in the hierarchy are duplicated.  Ids are used to make the nodes in the EMT unique, but I haven't found documentation on how to use something other than name to map a record. For example, how do I map a records to child_2 below, rather than child_1 if both are named "A child"?

```
Root [id=root]
|-One parent @id=parent_1 @parent=root
|   '- A child @id=child_1 @parent=parent_1
'-Other parent @id=parent_2 @parent=root
    '- A child @id=child 2 @parent=parent_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read through the DTD File (for instance C:\Endeca\PlatformServices\11.1.0\conf\dtd\external_dimensions.dtd ), you can try the following.

```html
                <node name="One" id="1" classify="false">
                    <synonym name="1"/>
                </node>
```

... where you could specify alternative values as the synonyms.  "One" would be displayed.  If your source data has "One", it would not map (because classify=false).  Your source data would have to have "1" in order to be mapped.

I'm not 100% sure since I don't have an EMT to play with, FYI.